# DAO usage in Excel VBA locking Access database

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, dao

When I use DAO in Excel VBA to INSERT into an Access database, it performs the transaction fine but prevents the Access database from being opened externally until I close the Excel workbook. Interestingly, this does not happen if the Access database is already open when the VBA code runs.

This is a minimum working example that demonstrates the problem. Again, the row is inserted fine, but unless the Access database is already open when this code is run, the database can't be opened externally until the workbook is closed. This code also doesn't seem to prevent other users of this spreadsheet from accessing the database.

```
Sub add_provision()
    Dim wrk As DAO.Workspace
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    Set wrk = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    ' open_db() just calls wrk.OpenDatabase with a determined databaseand returns the result
    Set db = open_db(wrk)

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    Call wrk.BeginTrans

    Dim insert_sql As String

    insert_sql = "INSERT INTO Provision(kID, ProvisionDate, BookID) " _
                & "VALUES(123456, #2023-06-27#, 5)"

    Call db.Execute(insert_sql)
    Call wrk.CommitTrans(dbForceOSFlush)

normexit:
    Call db.Close
    Call wrk.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Set wrk = Nothing
    Exit Sub

cleanup:
    Call wrk.Rollback
    Resume normexit
End Sub
```

EDIT
Here is `open_db()`:

```
Function open_db(ByRef wrk As Workspace) As DAO.Database
    On Error GoTo end_function
    
    Dim db_name As String
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "original provision.xlsm" Then
        db_name = ' redacted path to development db
    Else
        db_name = ' redacted path to production db
    End If
    Set open_db = wrk.OpenDatabase(db_name)
    
    Exit Function
end_function:
    Set open_db = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What is the code for open_db()? Why do you need to use DAO? Why do you need to use Transaction? Why use Excel as GUI to database?

Comment: 1. `open_db()` is little more than a wrapper around `wrk.OpenDatabase()`. It just determines which database of a couple to use (production vs development, really). 2. I'm new to VBA and DAO was the first option I came across that seemed to work well. Should I consider transitioning to a different option? 3. In the original code, I'm running multiple INSERTs at once as one transaction. I just simplified it a little to demonstrate my issue. 4. The big product is an easy to use interface to the database, written in Excel, that provides more flexibility and security than straight Access would.

Comment: I have one Excel file that interacts with Access db but only to pull data. It uses DAO and ADO methods. I have no problem opening Access db after running the Excel code. Are you able to open Access db before performing INSERT actions?

Comment: Set breakpoints in Excel code and attempt to open Access file at various stages. When do you lose the ability to open db?

Comment: I am able to open the Access DB before running the code posted in the question. No other VBA runs before then. With breakpoints it appears the database is locked when the open_db function is called but before any code in the function executes. The database stays locked from here until the close of the workbook or until I reset the VBA project.

Comment: If I remove the call to `open_db()` and open the database in `add_provision()` with `Set db = wrk.OpenDatabase("path to db")`, that's the line that locks the database. All other behavior seems the same.

Comment: I tested your code through `Set db` line with breakpoint. No problem independently manually opening Access db at that point. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Well that rules out the code at least. Thank you for trying it! I'll have to pursue other avenues.